# Can I change my travel dates after applying for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I have applied for a UK visa specifying my intended travelling dates, but I need to change them. I haven't been issued a visa yet. Do I have to go through the whole application process again, or can it be amended?

Comment: Where are you in the application stage?  Also, how much of a change is it?

Comment: Please clarify your application stage.